# Empty element inserted into ArrayList when reading from command line

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, string-parsing

I have code that i'm running to get a list of user groups from the command line of a given user, using the following code:

```
private ArrayList<String> accessGroups = new ArrayList<String>();

public void setAccessGroups(String userName) {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec("/* code to get users */");

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        String line = null;

        // This code needs some work
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null){  
            System.out.println("#" + line);
            String[] temp;
            temp = line.split("\\s+");
            if(line.contains("GRPNAME-")) { 
                for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
                    accessGroups.add(temp[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        // For debugging purposes, to delete
        System.out.println(accessGroups);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code to get users returns a result containing the following:

```
#Local Group Memberships      *localgroup1          *localgroup2      
#Global Group memberships     *group1               *group2    
#                             *group3               *group4       
#                             *GRPNAME-1            *GRPNAME-2
```

The code is designed to extract anything beginning with GRPNAME-. This works fine, it's just if I print the `ArrayList` I get:

```
[, *GRPNAME-1, *GRPNAME-2]
```

There's an reference to a string of `""`. Is there a simple way I can alter the regex, or another solution I could try to remove this from occurring at the point of being added.

The expected output is:

```
[*GRPNAME-1, *GRPNAME-2]
```

Edit: answered, edited output to reflect changes in code.

Comment: Verify if the `String` to add is not empty.

Comment: what is input and expected output? Please clear the requirement.

Comment: where is `fliclearusers` in the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this tokenization as presented from this snippet:

```
line.split("\\s+");
```

Use a pattern to match `\S+` and add them to your collection. For example:

```
// Class level
private static final Pattern TOKEN = Pattern.compile("\\S+");

// Instance level
{
    Matcher tokens = TOKEN.matcher(line);
    while (tokens.find())
        accessGroups.add(tokens.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer in the end, in place of:

```
temp = line.split("\\s+");
```

use:

```
temp = line.trim().split("\\s+");
```